# Recibir datos de un loop en un metodo del controlador en la vista laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un metodo en el controlador que hace unos inserts a una tabla, y quiero que por cada insert, la barra aumente, pero este loop esta en el controlador. Hay alguna manera de hacer eso?

```js
   //codigo javascript
$.ajax(
  {
    type: 'get',
    url: "{{ route('ruta') }}",
    data: { 'p1' : p1,
            'p2' : p2 },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    xhr: function() {
       var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(e){
           if(e.currentTarget.response.trim() == ''){
              recibidos++;
              aumentarBarra(recibidos);
            }
                        
       });
        return xhr;
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      //codigo del success            
                
    }
 });
```

```html
//php
function Metodo(Request $request){
  
  @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
  if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
  
  .. la la la se hacen unas busquedas
  $ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  foreach($ids as $key => $id){
    //hacer un insert a la tabla
    
    echo ' ';
    ob_get_contents();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
  }
}
```

En mi local funciona, pero en el servidor de pruebas, no tengo acceso al php.ini ni a las configuraciones del server, por eso me parece que el flush no funciona, hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Mm podrías mantener el progreso en sesión y en javascript ejecutar un $.get para que te regrese el progreso de la acción

Tu javascript:

```
$.ajax(
  {
    type: 'get',
    url: "{{ route('ruta') }}",
    data: { 'p1' : p1,
            'p2' : p2 },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    beforeSend: function(){
        getProgreso();
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      //codigo del success            

    }
 });

function getProgreso(){
    setInterval(function(){
            $.getJSON('/ruta-progreso', function(data) {
                //acá manejas el proceso con una barra o lo que estés usando
            });
        }, 1000);
}
```

En tu controlador:

```
public function getProgreso() {
    return response()->json(array(session('progresoInsert')));
}

public function Metodo(Request $request){

  @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
  if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

  .. la la la se hacen unas busquedas

  $ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  $progreso = 1;
  $total = count($ids);
  foreach($ids as $key => $id){
    //hacer un insert a la tabla

    echo ' ';
    ob_get_contents();
    ob_flush();
    flush();


    //podrías aplicar una regla de 3
    $progreso = (($progreso * 100) / $total);
    $progreso++;
    session(['progresoInsert' => $progreso]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Habria un inconveniente al momento de por ejemplo, realizar ese proceso en dos ventanas diferentes?

Comment: @PaolaCasianosipac Si habría inconveniente, si quieres que el progreso se muestre a la par en diferentes navegadores, ventanas, computadoras, etc. lo que estarías buscando sería websockets.